# 14.04 - Make synclient changes persistent

Tags: 14.04, xorg, touchpad, synaptics

No other related thread has a definite answer for this.

Some say to create `50-synaptics.conf` in `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/` , while others say to use the one in usr/share/X11.

Creating `etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/50-synaptics.conf` broke my machine and forced me to boot into CLI to delete the folder.

Using the one in `usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/` had no effect on synclient settings.

There are some other solutions which is basically to make a startup script, but I feel like that is not an optimal solution.

Does anyone have a working way to make synclient settings persistent using a conf file?

Comment: Is there already a "50-synaptics.conf" in "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"? It is recommended to define a new .conf in this folder with a startnumber > 50 and define your settings in the "InputClass" section.

Comment: Did you reboot/restart the X server after editing `usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/`?

Answer (score 0):

Just ran into this. The first option that you list is the one I went with. You need to make sure that you rename the file to a number greater than 50. In my case, I created the file `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/51-touchpad-config.conf`. After restarting, I was able to confirm it worked with the `synclient` command. In my case, I wanted to persist changes to the `HorizScrollDelta` option, so my file looked as follows.

```
Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "desensitize horizontal scrolling so it doesn't trigger when vertically scrolling."
        MatchIsTouchpad "on"
        Option "HorizScrollDelta" "650"
EndSection
```